# itext transfers my letters to html letter codes

Tags: java, servlets, itext

I have a pdf for in which user copies a text from his desktop and on submit a pdf is generated. I use **itext-2.1.7**. But since We use some non standard letter these are converted to their html code character codes. This is my servlet for doc I use "application/pdf;charset=UTF-8".

```
BaseFont bf;
try {
  HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
  if (session.getAttribute("taxnumber") == null || session.getAttribute("email") == null || session.getAttribute("password") == null) {
    request.setAttribute("message", "The user does not exist in our database");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/Login.jsp").forward(request, response);
  }
  String title = request.getParameter("doctitle");
  String date = request.getParameter("docdate");
  String text = request.getParameter("brokerstext");
  String[] newdate = date.split("/");
  Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
  document.open();

  document.add(new Paragraph(newdate[1] + "/" + newdate[0] + "/" + newdate[2]));
  document.add(new Paragraph(title));
  document.add(new Paragraph(text));
  document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
  document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
  document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
  document.add(new LineSeparator());
  document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
  document.add(new LineSeparator());
  document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
  document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
  document.add(new Paragraph("Brokers's digital signature Clients's digital signature"));

  PdfFormField field1 = PdfFormField.createSignature(writer);
  field1.setWidget(new Rectangle(72, 100, 172, 200), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT);
  field1.setFieldName("mySig1");
  field1.setTitle("Klijent1");
  field1.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
  field1.setPage();
  PdfAppearance tp1 = PdfAppearance.createAppearance(writer, 72, 48);
  tp1.rectangle(0.5f, 0.5f, 71.5f, 47.5f);
  tp1.stroke();
  field1.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, tp1);
  writer.addAnnotation(field1);

  PdfFormField field2 = PdfFormField.createSignature(writer);
  field2.setWidget(new Rectangle(372, 100, 472, 200), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT);
  field2.setFieldName("mySig2");
  field2.setTitle("Klijent2");
  field2.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
  field2.setPage();
  PdfAppearance tp2 = PdfAppearance.createAppearance(writer, 72, 48);
  tp2.rectangle(0.5f, 0.5f, 71.5f, 47.5f);
  tp2.stroke();
  field2.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, tp2);
  writer.addAnnotation(field2);

  document.close();
```

I did use

```
public static final String FONT = "C:/Windows/Fonts/segoeui.ttf";   
bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
document.add(new Paragraph(title,new Font(bf, 12)));
```

buy putting in some other fonts but it did not help the text that looks like this "o deponovanim novčanim" transfers to this "o deponovanim nov&#....." , stackoverflow displays it the same . So in pdf i get a html code of my letters . How to display it right .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write the values of `title` and `text` to the log file as plain text. There's a 99.9% chance that they contain the same HTML codes. If they do, you don't have an iText-related problem. Instead you have a Servlet problem ;-)

Comment: You are correct "There's a 99.9% chance that they contain the same HTML codes" what now...

Comment: You need to "unescape" the Strings. The class XMLUtil has a method for this: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/xml/XMLUtil.html#unescapeXML%28java.lang.String%29